# Find the least $n>1$ such that $\cos(\pi/n)$ can NOT be written as $a+\sqrt{b} + \sqrt[3]{c}$ for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm currently learning algebraic number theory, and this is an exercise of the first chapter of my lecture (regarding symmetric polynomials, minimal polynomials, conjugates) that I've been struggling with for the past few days.

Uptill now, I've been completely stuck: $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$ should (but I'm not sure how to rigorously prove that) have a minimal polynomial of degree at most $6$, so I think I should look for $n$ with $\cos(\pi/n)$ of degree $n$, but how to move forward?

Thank you.

Comment: To determine the algebraic degree of $\cos(\pi/n)$, note that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\pi/n))=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n}+\zeta_{2n}^{-1})$ has index $2$ inside $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})$ for $n\ge 2$. Moreover, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})$ has degree $\varphi(2n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Actually, I've only just begun this course, so I don't know what you mean by "$\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\pi/n))$ has index $2$ inside $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})$" :-(

Comment: This exercise is one next to the chapter about symmetric polynomials, conjugates and minimal polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$), so I thought it could be cracked with these tools?

Comment: It's a strange question to ask so early in the course, but <i>maybe</i> if you know about conjugates you might be able to prove that:

$$ \ $$

1. The conjugates of $\cos(\pi/n)$ are all real. 

$$ \  $$

2. The conjugates of $a + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt[3]{c}$ are only all real if $b > 0$ and $c$ is a cube (which may as well be $c=0$ absorbing it in to the $a$ term, so if they coincide the degree of $\cos(\pi/n)$ is $1$ or $2$.

$$ \ $$

3. $\cos(\pi/7)$ is a root of $8 z^3 + 4 z^22 - 4 z - 1 = 0$ which is irreducible.

Comment: OK thank you for your help! I think I succeeded. 

1. $U_{n-1}$ (which is the $n-1$th Chebychev of 2nd kind) has only real roots, and it does annulate $\cos(\pi/n)$, so the latter only has real conjugates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, thanks to @user994373.

We want to exhib the least $n$ such that $\cos(\pi/n)$ can not be written as $a+\sqrt{b} + \sqrt[3]{c}$ for some rationals $a,b,c$.

$\textbf{First step : $\cos(\pi/n)$ has only real conjugates}$.
We define Chebychev polynomials of second kind as the polynomial verifying :
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
U_0 = 1\\
U_1 = 2X\\
U_{n+1} = 2XU_n - U_{n-1}
\end{array}\right.$$
By induction, these polynomials have only rational coefficients, and $\deg U_n = n$.

Moreover, one can prove that $$\forall \theta\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \pi\mathbb{Z},\quad U_{n-1}(\cos(\theta)) = \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$
It follows that $\cos(\pi/n),\cos(2\pi/n),\cos(3\pi/n),\dots,\cos((n-1)\pi/n)$ are the $n-1$ roots of $U_{n-1}$. Thus, $\cos(\pi/n)$ only has real conjugates.

$\textbf{Second step : conditions for $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$ to only have real conjugates}$.
As a corollary of the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, the conjugates of $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$ lie in $$ S = \{a\pm \sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c},\; a\pm \sqrt{b}+j\sqrt[3]{c},\; a\pm \sqrt{b}+j^2\sqrt[3]{c}\}$$
where $j:= \exp(2i\pi/3)$.

If $b=0$, it is enough for $\sqrt[3]{c}$ to not be rational so that $a+\sqrt[3]{c}$ admits at least two conjugates (both in $S$), one at least being non-real.

If $b>0$, we see that $$\begin{align*}P(X) &= \big(X - (a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c})\big)\big(X - (a-\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c})\big)\\ &= X^2 - 2(a+\sqrt[3]{c})X + K\end{align*}$$
is not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ if $\sqrt[3]{c}\not\in \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$ has at least $3$ conjugates (all in $S$) if $\sqrt[3]{c}\not\in \mathbb{Q}$, and at least one of them is then non-real.

As a result, the condition for $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$ to having only real conjugates is that $\sqrt[3]{c}\in \mathbb{Q}$ (which is equivalent to saying $c=0$, without loss of generality, as $\sqrt[3]{c}$ can be "absorbed" in $a$).

$\textbf{Third step : conclusion.}$
Because $\cos(\pi/n)$ only has real conjugates, if it can be expressed as $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}$, then $c=0$. But the minimal polynomial of $a+\sqrt{b}$ is at most of degree $2$. Similarly, if the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\pi/n)$ is of degree $1$ or $2$, then $\cos(\pi/n)$ can be expressed as $a+\sqrt{b}$ for some rationals $a$ and $b$.
Therefore, we're looking for the least $n$ such that $\cos(\pi/n)$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $3$ (or more, if none have degree $3$).
With a bit of time, we find that $n=7$ works (the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\pi/7)$ is $8 x^3 - 4 x^2 - 4 x + 1$).

Comment: remark : One could have shown that $\cos(\pi/n)$ only has real conjugates by using the fact that $\cos(\pi/n)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\pi/n} + e^{-i\pi/n})$. If $P(X) = (X+1/X)/2$, conjugates of $P(\alpha)$ are in $\{P(\beta)\,|\,\beta\}$ where $\beta$ go through all conjugates of $\alpha$. And $P(\beta)$ are thus all reals.